# Accordions inside tabs, respectively // bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to have an accordion per tab. A couple of glitches(specified below) happen with the code that i have.

1) data in first tab appear but if i switch to another tab and then go back to the first one, it doesnt show corrent accordion.

2) fourth tab doesnt even show up its accordion

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">

  <li role "presentation" class="active">
    <a href="#latest-event" data-toggle="tab">

      <p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Latest Events</p>
    </a>

  </li>

  <li role "presentation">
    <a href="#latest-offer" data-toggle="tab">

      <p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span> Latest Offers</p>
    </a>

  </li>

  <li role "presentation">
    <a href="#newest-sigh" data-toggle="tab">

      <p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Newest Sightings</p>
    </a>

  </li>

  <li role "presentation">
    <a href="#latest-news" data-toggle="tab">

      <p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Latest News</p>
    </a>

  </li>

</ul>

<div class="tab-content">

  <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="lastest-event">

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1" role="tablist">

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#panel1" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">Title 1</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

            <p>content</p>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#panel2" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">Title 2/h2>

         </div>

         <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

           <p> content </p>

          </div>

         </div>

        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">

         <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#panel3" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">Title 3</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

            <img src="images/eventos/PandB.jpg" class="image-responsive">

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading" data-parent="#accordion1" role="tab">

          <a href="#">
            <h2 class="panel-tittle">View All Upcoming Events</h2> 
          </a>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="latest-offer">

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist">

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" data-target="#panel5" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">title 5</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="panel5" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

            <p>content</p>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" data-target="#panel6" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">title 6</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="panel6" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

            <p>content</p>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" data-target="#panel7" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">title 7</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="panel7" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

            <p>content</p>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" data-target="#panel8" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">title 8</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="panel8" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

            <p>content</p>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="newest-sigh">

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion3" role="tablist">

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" data-target="#panel9" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">title 9</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="panel9" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

            <p>content</p>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" data-target="#panel10" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">title 10</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="panel10" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

            <p>content</p>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" data-target="#panel11" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">title 11</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="panel11" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

            <p>content</p>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" data-target="#panel12" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">title 12</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="panel12" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

            <p>content</p>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="lastest-news">

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion4" role="tablist">

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" data-target="#panel13" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">title 13</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="panel13" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

            <p>content</p>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" data-target="#panel14" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">title 14</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="panel14" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

            <p>content</p>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" data-target="#panel15" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">title 15</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="panel15" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

            <p>content</p>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collaped" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" data-target="#panel16" role="tab">

          <h2 class="panel-tittle">title 16</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="panel16" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">

          <div class="panel body">

            <p>content</p>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your markup is invalid and missing the proper closing `</div>`. Also you have `<li role "presentation">`, it should be `<li role="presentation">`. Also you have `panel-tittle` which should be `panel-title` and `panel body` which should be `panel-body`, etc.

Comment: And the reason why your tabs don't work is because your tabs are targeting #la**t**est-news and your div ID is **#lastest-news**, the same goes for the #latest-events